# Deploying Orchard - over 700MG

Tags: orchardcms

I have followed different threads here and there related to deploying Orchard but for some reason, they all **keep producing a 700MG site**.

I have **added maybe 10 pages max** to the existing site, so something is wrong.

I see that all modules are copied, and each of them has a repeated set of .dll on each of their BIN folders.

> I have installed Orchard from the Microsoft Web Platform Installer.
> I am using VS 2010 Ultimate
> I am using SQL Compact (for this site)

Any thought will be much appreciated, cause for some reason I do NOT want to believe MS is producing such a mess on deploying a simple site, repeating sooo many times the same DLLs for each module.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yeah, if you do a dumb copy of everything, each and every module has a copy of all the dlls in its bin folder, which are just going to sit there doing nothing. You need to either do a real web deploy, which should do the right thing and only deploy what you need, or build from the command-line when you need to deploy using build "compile;package".

It's explained here: http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Building-and-deploying-Orchard-from-a-source-code-drop

Comment: Yes for some reason, when I was doing the Web Deployment, it was creating that 700MG. Not sure what changed but all of a sudden, now is only 40MG.  Much better :)  !!

Comment: You could also use the *ClickToBuild.cmd* to build Orchard and create a cleaned up and minimalized deployment package. It's located in *build\Stage* folder after successful build. Just grab that and copy to your web server.

Comment: Well, ClickToBuild does what build compile;package is doing, plus a few other things that you don't want, such as running tests.